# Count when there are 6 or more unique occurrences in a column then in a new column have a string that identifies it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with patients, their services, date of services, ect... If a patient has 6+ unique services in a month then in my select statement
I want a new column to have the word "Full Month" in it.

Comment: We aren't a code-writing service.  We're here to help you if you get stuck, not to do your work for you.  What have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple group by

Set up data

```
create table #patient
(
  patientId int,
  serviceId int,
  dt date
)

insert into #patient values
(1, 1, '2016-01-02'),
(1, 1, '2016-01-05'),
(1, 1, '2016-01-07'),
(1, 1, '2016-01-12'),
(1, 1, '2016-01-16'),
(1, 1, '2016-01-20'),
(1, 1, '2016-01-25'),
(1, 2, '2016-01-02'),
(1, 2, '2016-01-02'),
(2, 1, '2016-01-02'),
(2, 1, '2016-01-02')
```

Get the result

```
select patientId, serviceId, count(*) AS Cnt
, case 
    when count(*) >= 6 then 'Full Month'
    else 'Not Full Month'
  end AS YourNewColumn
from #patient
group by patientId, serviceId, month(dt)
```

It will show

```
+-----------+-----------+-----+----------------+
| patientId | serviceId | Cnt | YourNewColumn  |
+-----------+-----------+-----+----------------+
|         1 |         1 |   7 | Full Month     |
|         1 |         2 |   2 | Not Full Month |
|         2 |         1 |   2 | Not Full Month |
+-----------+-----------+-----+----------------+
```

Comment: For what reason a correct and well explained answer gets down-vote?

Comment: It's probably one of the common "I don't like this question or people that answer it" downvotes; So here's an upvote to balance that out :)

Comment: Thank you man!! Whoever he/she was, down voted for Q and both answers :)

Comment: Yeah, it happens far too often.

Comment: This looks really close to what im trying to do. It looks like this creates a new column with the total occurances. What im trying to do is get a count of each distinct service code in a month and have that count in a new column.                                                                                             select patientId, serviceId, count(*)
from #patient
group by patientId, serviceId, month(dt)
--having count(*) >=

Comment: I see, Look as my changed query

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you could use a `GROUP BY` query on your specific patient identifier to get all of the results for a specific patient over a date range as seen below :

```
  SELECT PatientId,
         CASE WHEN COUNT(ServiceId) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FullMonth
    FROM Patients 
   WHERE ServiceDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY PatientId, ServiceId
```

You can [see an overly simplified example of this here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0edf4/1).